# What does "You are my weather" mean?

Tags: phrases, vocabulary

I would like to ask what the phrase "You are my weather" mean.
The context is in an acknowledgement section at the end of a book where the author pays tribute to her family. She said that she would like to thank her mother and say "You are my weather".

Comment: That does sound strange. What book/author?

Comment: It immediately suggests to me that the writer is saying that her family, especially her mother, is the source of her emotional wellbeing or state, just like the sun, clouds, wind, rain, etc, are the source of the wellbeing of nature on the earth.

Comment: @Mitch: The Happiness Project by Gretchen Rubin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the popular "you are my sunshine" to mean "you light up my life/make me feel happy and warm," by extension I guess it means "My environment is based on your demeanor."

Compare: "Happy wife, happy life."